# Cellular Automaton with larger rules

Tags: cellular-automata, substitutionsystem

I want to implement a Cellular Automaton with the following rules:

```
00011
 010

01011
 110

10011
 010

11000
 010

11010
 011

11001
 010
```

All remaining patterns shall stay "the same", like:

```
abcde
 bcd
```

A valid example sequence based on these rules would be:

```
111110000
111101000
111011000
111010100
110110100
110101100
101110010
```

Another way to state the rules is: "110" -> "101" and "011" -> "101", except "11011" occurs then neither of the first two rules is applied on the central three elements.

As these are "larger" rules as compared to the normal nearest neighbour rules I have no idea how to best implement these. Also the should operate on "larger" starting strings like  maybe 128 bits long.

Any suggestions welcome. Especially short code is appreciated. (Merry X-max to all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an interesting problem that with a little manipulation can be modelled with [`SubstitutionSystem`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubstitutionSystem.html) like below:

```
rules = {"00011" -> "00101",
   "01011" -> "01101",
   "10011" -> "10101",
   "11000" -> "10100",
   "11010" -> "10110",
   "11001" -> "10101"};


SubstitutionSystem[rules, "111110000", 6]

(* Out (without quotation): 

111110000
111101000
111011000
111010100
110110100
110101100
101101100

*)
```

But to preserve the string, the left and right sides of rules should be the same size which in some special cases can override themselves and lead to an incorrect result.

---

Since your rules are the same, we can easily write a general case for them like the one below:

```
ClearAll[CustomSubstitutionSystem];

CustomSubstitutionSystem[text_String, rules_Association] := 
  Last @ CustomSubstitutionSystem[text, rules, 1];

CustomSubstitutionSystem[text_String, rules_Association, 
  iterations_Integer] := Module[{textResult = text
   , textLength = StringLength @ text
   , ruleLength = StringLength @ First @ Keys @ rules
   , textSlice, textOriginal},
  
  Prepend[text]@
  Table[
   textOriginal = textResult;
   
   Do[
    textSlice = 
     StringTake[
      textOriginal, {startIndex, startIndex + ruleLength - 1}];

    If[KeyExistsQ[rules, textSlice],

     textResult = StringReplacePart[textResult
        , rules[textSlice]
        , {startIndex + 1, startIndex + ruleLength - 2}];
     
     ], {startIndex, textLength - ruleLength + 1}];
   textResult
   
   , {iterations}]
  ]
```

The first argument is the text, the second is the rules as `Association` and the third is optional, the number of iterations to apply.

The left and right sides of all the rules should be the **same size**.

Basically, we take a slice from the text and look at whether it's in the rules or not, if yes, replace part of our copy and check for the next slice.

Since the rules can replace more than one character, the next slice still can override part of the current slice if they both have a rule. The order of replacement is from left to the right.

```
rules = Association @ {"00011" -> "010",
    "01011" -> "110",
    "10011" -> "010",
    "11000" -> "010",
    "11010" -> "011",
    "11001" -> "010"};

CustomSubstitutionSystem["111110000", rules, 6]

(* Out (without quotation):

111110000
111101000
111011000
111010100
110110100
110101100
101110100

*)
```

Note the last row is different from the `SubstitutionSystem` result and your example.

It should work for any case like yours where rules in format `k -> v`, have `StringLength[k] == StringLength[v] + 2` attribute.

Comment: I wanted actually a toy model for 'diffusion' and it's actually derived from problem 23 of "advent of code 2022" which the significantly different 2D version of this. I think it could be even interpreted as a model for phase transitions. I intend to submit the sequence for a certain infinite starting string to oeis (usind decimal encoding for the sequence elements.

Comment: Thank you @BenIzd , this is the perfect answer!

Comment: @RaphaelJ.F.Berger I'm glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that 5 element patterns replaces only the middle 3 elements. With this we can define a the following rules:

```
rules0 =
  {PatternSequence[0, 0, 0, 1, 1] -> {0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
   PatternSequence[0, 1, 0, 1, 1] -> {0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
   PatternSequence[1, 0, 0, 1, 1] -> {1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
   PatternSequence[1, 1, 0, 0, 0] -> {1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
   PatternSequence[1, 1, 0, 1, 0] -> {1, 0, 1, 1, 0},
   PatternSequence[1, 1, 0, 0, 1] -> {1, 0, 1, 0, 1}};
rules = {x1___, #[[1]], x2___} -> {x1, Sequence @@ #[[2]], x2} & /@ 
   rules0;
```

To test this we create some bit string:

```
SeedRandom[1];
dat = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 20]
(* {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

and apply the rules repeatedly (because of overlap):

```
dat //. rules
(* {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for trying! That seems not to work: dat={1,1,1,0,0,0}; dat /. rules; dat /. rules yields in the first and second iteration both times: {1,1,0,1,0,0}, while it should give {1,0,1,1,0,0} for the second round of rules.

Comment: I have added an example to make it clearer how the rules shall be applied.

Comment: If you apply the rules correctly, it will work. at={1,1,1,0,0,0}; dat=dat /. rules; dat= dat /. rules

Comment: I am sorry @DanielHuber  it does not work for me. Can you verify the sample sequence I have added to the question?

Comment: `dat = {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0};Print[dat = dat /. rules];Print[dat = dat /. rules];`outputs: `{1,1,0,1,0,0}` and `{1,0,1,1,0,0}` MMA version 13.2